# jQuery bootstrap tabs template append

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I am trying to dynamically add bootstrap tabs based on a button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script id="tabTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab'+nextTab+'">tab' +nextTab+' content</div>
</script>

<a href="#" id="btnAdd"><i class="icon-plus-sign-alt"></i> Add Tab</a>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Hello tab #1 content...</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextTab = $('#tabs li').size()+1;

    // create the tab
    $('<li><a href="#tab'+nextTab+'" data-toggle="tab">Tab '+nextTab+'</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');

    // create the tab content
    $('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab'+nextTab+'">tab' +nextTab+' content</div>').appendTo('.tab-content');

    // make the new tab active
    $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
});

});
```

I am trying to put the  '// create the tab content' into a template but still have the tab id increment.

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qznw5x0z/1/)

Can anybody help with this?
I cannot seem to get it working using a template, and need the tab to house a lot more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/rn0kjkyw/1/)

I needed to pass the javascript variable/value with the template:

```
$.tmpl( tabTemplate, { "device" : nextTab }).appendTo('.tab-content');
```

and referance it within my template:

```
<script id="tabTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <div class='tab-pane' id='tab${device}'>${device}</div>
</script>
```

hope this helps somebody.